# FirstOrDefault on List not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have a list like

```
var listDataDemo = model.Jobs.ToList();
```

The listDataDemo  has data like following

```
Count = 13
[0]: {PaymentItemModel}
```

when i type in Immediate Window like

```
listData.FirstOrDefault()
```

it gives result

```
Amount: 0
Date: {1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM}
Method: "PayPal"
PayerName: null
PayerNumber: null
PaymentDetailType: Payment
TransactionId: null
```

But when i write(code in my class)

```
var demoVal = listData.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Method=="PayPal")

The name 'demoVal' does not exist in the current context(no value)
```

How to get a value from LIST.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is working fine for me. Just have a look:

```
        List<test> testList = new List<test>();

        testDB testObj = new testDB();
        testList = testObj.fn_getAll();
        var abc = testList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == 3);
```

And you just try to change the name of the variable, this might be causing the issue.

I hope it will help you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff, the predicate you're providing to FirstOrDefault to filter results looks like it has a syntax error: `(p=>p.Method="PayPal")` should be `(p=>p.Method=="PayPal")`.

Granted this was probably a typo, for completeness:

'=' is an assignment operator, for when you want to assign a value to a variable.

'==' is an equality comparison operator, for when you want to test equality between values and get 'true' or 'false'.

---

Edited to answer beyond the typo...

Are you using Entity Framework?
EF has extension methods for FirstOrDefault also, except the filter parameter is an SQL query. If you're using EF, then you could be missing the following:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I am so sorry, i had a typo when framing question. This is what i am using (p=>p.Method=="PayPal")

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the predicate in your call to `FirstOrDefault` has a typo.  You want `==` for comparison, not `=` for assignment.

Comment: listData.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Method == "PayPal") this is what i am using in code. Sorry i had a typo while framing the question.